# Probems with merging same values for different keys in dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, merge

I have a lot of Coordinates, for which i've created a large dictionary for which individual keys might have the same list of values. I want to merge those keys with the same list of values, as to get a count of how many keys have a given list of values. I've managed to merge them, but for some reason some of the values are reversed and therefore not properly merged.

So far I've tried creating a new dictionary with the merged keys as a tuple and kept the values as a list. Furthermore i only keep those list of values which has two or more keys.

My start dictionary

```
start_dict = {
    'Key1': [243928620, 243938319],
    'Key2': [243935130, 243935973],
    'Key3': [243928620, 243938319],
    'Key4': [243928628, 243938315],
    'Key5': [243928628, 243938315],
    'Key6': [243930418, 243933130, 243933141]
}
```

For which Key1 & 3 have the same list of values, same for Key4 & 5.
So i've merged them using

```
from collections import defaultdict
New_dict= defaultdict(list)
for k, v in sorted(start_dict.items()):
    New_dict[tuple(v)].append(k)

final_dict = {tuple(v):set(k) for k, v in New_dict.items()}
```

With the expected results being

```
{(‘Key1’,’Key2’): {243928620, 243938319}, (‘Key4’,’Key5’): {243928628, 243938315}}
```

But for some reason it ends up as

```
{(‘Key1’,’Key2’): {243928620, 243938319}, (‘Key4’,’Key5’): {243938315,243928628}}
```

Where the values in a single list is switched, which is a problem since the order of the coordinates matter.

Of course the actual dataset is larger, and the merging works for 49/50 of the keys and list of value pairs.

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Comment: You're using set() so the contents of the set are in numerical order. You need a different method to merge them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of using an intermediate dictionary was correct, but the keys of this dictionary should be the *values* of the original dictionary:

```
new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in sorted(start_dict.items()):
    new_dict[tuple(v)].append(k)

final_dict = { tuple(v): list(k) for k, v in new_dict.items() if len(v) > 1 }
```

No need to use a `set` as we don't care about the uniqueness of values within the lists themselves.

Output:

```
{('Key1', 'Key3'): [243928620, 243938319], ('Key4', 'Key5'): [243928628, 243938315]}
```